# Define compound keys in FME

Tags: fme-form

I am running a process in FME 2014 to translate some data from an Excel to a PostgreSQL database.
My created table needs to have two primary keys (thus a composite key).
I have selected from the writer properties the columns which I want them to be PK but when I run the translation I get:

"Multiple primary keys specified in definition for table 'bom'. Only one primary key can be specified per table. Discarding primary key request for column 'item_code'"

How can I define composite keys in FME? Is it possible at all? If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all I created the table with the compound key in pgAdmin and I used an SQLExecutr transformer in FME with an INSERT query.
This way I avoid the problem although I don't know if there is another, cleaner solution.